# Find space-padded pairs of asterisks

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

I need to find poorly-formed markdown that breaks a particular markdown parser. I'm in search of a RegEx which will find cases where `**bold text**` is incorrectly padded with a space before or after the asterisks. For example `** this is wrong**` and `**this is also **` as is `** this one too **`, but `**this is correct**`. Naturally, lines can often contain both.  For example, here are some test cases:

```
This line is **correct** and **properly marked down**.
But this line **is not** because ** the second bold is wrong**.
** Also** this line is wrong **even though this is right**.
```

I've tried `(?:\*\*[^\*]*\s\*\*)`, but that actually captures the parts *between* (the parts not enclosed in asterisks).  Any advice?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Actually using a text editor (Atom) but I'm pretty sure the underlying RegEx engine is Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will be helpful, Here we are using combination which can be possible `**spaces words spaces**` , `**words spaces**` and `**spaces words**`

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/HufDkS/4)

**Regex:** `(?<=\s|^)(?:\*\*)(\s+([^\*]+)\s+|\s+([^\*]+)|([^\*]+)\s+)(?:\*\*)`

> **1.** `(?<=\s|^)` positive look behind space or start of string
>
> **2.** `(?:\*\*)` match `**`
>
> **3.** `(\s+([^\*]+)\s+` this will match `space` then `somewords` and then `space`
>
> **4.** `\s+([^\*]+)` match `spaces` and then all till not `*` (not including `*`)
>
> **5.** `([^\*]+)\s+)` match somewords then `spaces`
>
> **6.** `(?:\*\*)` match `**`

Comment: I think he needs to match the poorly formatted markdown only. the demo shows that it find all markdown poorly formatted and the good ones

Comment: @MostafaHussein I have updated my post you can check it.

Comment: I think you've done a fair job on this one, so I'm going to gift this refinement to you.  `(?<=^| )\*{2}(?: +[^*]+ +| +[^*]+|[^*]+ +)\*{2}`  this will boost your pattern's performance (steps) by 37.5% ...measured by your demo's sample input.  https://regex101.com/r/HufDkS/5

Comment: Thanks, @SahilGulati and @mickmackusa!  Only wrinkle:  I'm using Javascript (inside Atom, text editor based on Javascript). As I understand it, Javascript RegEx doesn't support positive look behind. How might I adjust the RegEx to replace the lookbehind with something that will work in Javascript?

Comment: Here's what I've come up with to work around the lack of Javascript lookbehind. Can anyone provide a better alternative?  `(?:\s|^)(?:\*\*)(?:\s+([^\*]+)\s+|(?:\s+([^\*]+))|([^\*]+)\s+)(?:\*\*)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
(?:\*\*\S.+?\S\*\*|(\*\*(?:\s.+?|.+?\s)\*\*))
```

Explanation:

```
                                      // Line must contain:
(?:\*\*\S.+?\S\*\*|                   // Correctly formatted block OR
           (                          // block with BAD formatting - space
            \*\*(?:\s.+?|             //   to the left of formatting OR
                         .+?\s)\*\*   //   to the right of formatting
           )
)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X7auSj/1)

Answer (score 0):

This is the javascript-friendly pattern that you require:

`^[^*]*(?:\*{2}[^ ][^*]*[^ ]\*{2}[^*\n]*)*(\*{2}(?: [^*]+|[^*]+ )\*{2}).*$`

Explanation (in casual terms):

```
^[^*]*                                # match anything preceding the first *
(?:\*{2}[^ ][^*]*[^ ]\*{2}[^*\n]*)*   # match zero or more valid sets of **'s, so we don't lose track of what is an opener/closer
(?:\*{2}(?: [^*]+|[^*]+ )\*{2})       # REQUIRE just one invalid ** set
.*$                                   # after one invalid set is found, it doesn't matter what trails it before end of line
```

[Regex Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/HufDkS/6)